# Sum total from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below Data Frame:

```
id A1 A2 B1 B2
1  6  7  8  9
2  7  8  9  7
3  4  5  6  5
4  4  5  4  9
5  6  7  6  3
```

And I want to sum the total for columns A1 + A2 and for columns B1 +B2
The expected output is this:

```
Sum_A  Sum_B
59      66
```

Sum_A = the sum of all the values in columns A1 and A2
Sum_B = the sum of all the values in columns B1 and B2

I'm working with pandas. Do you know how can I get the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) here.

```
out = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['A', 'B'], i='id', j='val').sum()

A    59
B    66
dtype: int64
```

To get the exact output as you mentioned in question you need to use

```
out = pd.DataFrame(out.values[None, :], columns= 'Sum_' + out.index)

   Sum_A  Sum_B
0     59     66
```

Or using `Series.to_frame().T.add_prefix('Sum')`

```
out.to_frame().T.add_prefix('Sum_')

   Sum_A  Sum_B
0     59     66
```

One approach is to use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) here.

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='id')
out = df.groupby(df['variable'].str[0])['value'].sum()

variable
A    59
B    66
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Same here too.

```
pd.DataFrame(out.values[None, :], columns='Sum_' + out.index)

variable  Sum_A  Sum_B
0            59     66

#OR

out.to_frame().T.add_prefix('Sum_')

variable  Sum_A  Sum_B
value        59     66
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove `id` column, sum values of columns and then aggregate by first letters with `sum`, last convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame`:

```
df = (df.drop('id', axis=1)
        .sum()
        .groupby(lambda x: x[0])
        .sum()
        .add_prefix('Sum_')
        .to_frame()
        .T)
print (df)
   Sum_A  Sum_B
0     59     66
```

Ot if want specify starting values of summed values use regex `^` is for start of strings with `A, B` in [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[df.filter(regex='^A').sum().sum(), 
                    df.filter(regex='^B').sum().sum()]], columns=['Sum_A','Sum_B'])
print (df)
   Sum_A  Sum_B
0     59     66
```